# MongoDB: multiprocessing update and '$inc' operation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a question on doing `$inc` update in MongoDB concurrently. In the manual page of `UpdateOne` and `findOneAndUpdate`, the subtlety of applying concurrent upsert was mentioned, and using a unique index for update matching is always recommended. The basic idea is that if two processes try to update a certain document which does not exists, and one finished querying before the other do the upsert, then without a unique index each process will create a new document, causing duplicates. In this case, indeed defining a unique index will prevent it from happening.

On the other hand, if my update is an increment operation, I wonder whether the unique index alone can save the day. Let's consider a simplified voting example, where a document looks like this:

```
{'name': 'Alice', 'votes': 0}, 
{'name': 'Bob', 'votes': 0}
...
```

Let's say `name` has been uniquely indexed (assuming no candidates with the same name). Suppose many processes are collecting the votings and doing the following update:

```
collection.update_one({'name': name}, {'$inc': {'votes': 1}}, upsert=False)
```

where `name` is a, say, python variable defined somewhere else. I wonder whether the same argument in the manual([see example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior)) can apply here.

Imagine at some moment, Alice got 5 votes. Process A and Process B both want to increase Alice's votes by 1. We expect Alice to have 7 votes if the two processes cooperate properly. However, if Process A locates Alice's document after B locates it but before B starts to do the increment, then Process A should have the knowledge that Alice have 5 votes, same as Process B. Therefore, even though A will do the modification after B releases the writing lock, it will change the votes to 5+1=6 votes, not 7.

Did I take the entire thing wrong? I think it has something to do with how `$inc` and how the single-document update actually works, but I'm not sure because:

1. this piece of info doesn't seem to be mentioned in `$inc` manual page, and
2. it's not easy to design an experiment for that since in order for two processes to collide, it seems necessary to have a large dataset. For a small dataset, it's too easy for one process to find the desired document and modify it before another process comes. In fact, I did an experiment on voting 2 candidates, and it nothing goes wrong no matter whether the name is uniquely indexed or not.

Any insights about how the locate-and-update works with `updateOne` and `findOneAndUpdate`, and how the `$inc` operation works are appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: didn't you mean `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `updateOneAndModify`? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: @Zarathustra Ah. You are right. Thanks. `updateOneandModify` is a funny name :)

Comment: this does not give you a definitive answer but some kinda hint https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#upsert-true

Comment: Hi @Zarathustra Thanks for your help but I think my question is more about the `$inc` than about the `upsert`?

Comment: well the $inc is used in the example ;)

Comment: @Zarathustra Hahah. Good point, but unfortunately the concurrency behavior of an update involving `$inc` was not discussed there...

Answer (score 0):

For **read** and **write** understanding, you need to understand **locking** Mechanism in MongoDB.

> Starting in MongoDB 3.2, the WiredTiger storage engine is the default storage engine.

**Essentials**

> The WiredTiger storage engine brings document level locking to
>   MongoDB, meaning that writes no longer block a collection or database.
>   While MMAP in 3.0 brought collection level locking, multiple writes to
>   the same collection will still cause the writes to be applied serially
>   and can starve reads from the collection as reads have to wait for the
>   writes to finish. WiredTiger gets rid of the limitation allowing
>   multiple writes to happen concurrently against the same collection.
>   This means that writes and reads scale with the CPU, whereas in MMAP
>   there was a low ceiling for CPU scaling as the locks reduced the
>   throughput.

As per **WiredTiger storage engine**

> once a write request comes in, all readers are blocked until the write
>   completes for a particular collection.

Reference link: 1.[OverviewLink](http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/wiredtiger/) , 2.[aboutStorageEngin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/)

**findAndModify Behavior**

```
Upsert and Unique Index
```

> When the findAndModify command includes the upsert: true option and
>   the query field(s) is not uniquely indexed, the command could insert a
>   document multiple times in certain circumstances.

**To prevent the creation of multiple duplicate documents, create a unique index on the name field. With the unique index in place, then the multiple findAndModify commands will exhibit one of the following behaviors:**

> Exactly one findAndModify successfully inserts a new document. Zero or
>   more findAndModify commands update the newly inserted document. Zero
>   or more findAndModify commands fail when they attempt to insert a
>   duplicate. If the command fails due to a unique index constraint
>   violation, you can retry the command. Absent a delete of the document,
>   the retry should not fail.

reference Link : [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that others are blocked when one starts to write. The question is, an update should consist of a kind of query stage to locate the document to be modified, and a writing stage. For example, the "concurrent upsert" problem is exactly caused by the fact that two processes finished the first stage before the other starts the writing stage and therefore acquire the writing lock. Therefore, the writing lock does not really help in this case. My question is, whether the same story apply to concurrent `$inc`.